# Create dynamic and complex content based on a <select> value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a complex div, which have unique id, and a nice design. I want to make a container, where these divs will appear based on a HTML select's value. With the createElement and append javascript methods, would be too complex to do it.

Is there any alternative to make it work, or do I really have to do it the old fashioned way?

**HTML and JavaScript**

```js
var divs = [];

document.getElementsByClassName('inn-quantity')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var n = +this.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].remove();
  }
  divs = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var inn = document.createElement("div");
    inn.className = "inn";
    var innContainer = document.getElementById("inn-container-id");
    innContainer.appendChild(inn);
    divs.push(inn);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="inn-select" class="inn-selector">
  <h1>Please choose</h1>
  <p>how many pages would you like to create?</p>
  <div class="select-style">
    <select class="inn-quantity">
          <option value="#">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="inn-container-id" class="inn-container"></div>
```

Comment: If you're hard-coding the `<select>` values anyway, you could just put in the HTML for every page with `display: none` and show the `<div>`s as appropriate. However if you want truly dynamic component adding you can't escape the DOM.

Comment: You are using (Dynamic & Complex) in one sentence and using pure javascript?

Comment: :D I see your point. With jquery I still should use these methods. It just make the code shorter. I'm searching for an easy appearance of the topic, but there isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest would be to insert everything and hide them. Then display just the ones you want according to the select value.

```js
var divs = [];

document.getElementsByClassName('inn-quantity')[0].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var n = +this.value;
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('complex-div');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (i <= n - 1) {
      divs[i].style.display = "block";
    } else {
      divs[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.complex-div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="inn-select" class="inn-selector">
  <h1>Please choose</h1>
  <p>how many pages would you like to create?</p>
  <div class="select-style">
    <select class="inn-quantity">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="inn-container-id" class="inn-container">
  <div class="complex-div">1</div>
  <div class="complex-div">2</div>
  <div class="complex-div">3</div>
  <div class="complex-div">4</div>
  <div class="complex-div">5</div>
  <div class="complex-div">6</div>
</div>
```

Another way, if you want to be able to reuse them or something is to store the elements in a hidden div and clone them where needed.